# how to recode with library(memisc)?

Tags: r

I just created a sample which gives the structure of my data:

```
     a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,2,3,5,4,5,6)
     b<-c(1,2,3,4,4,1,2,3,9,7,2,3,6,1,9,3,1,5,7,8)
     c<-c(1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0)
     d<-c(10,9,7,10,11,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3)
     e<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5)
     df<-data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)

     library(memisc)

      df_p1<- within(df,{
                        e<-recode(e,
                                    c(1,2,3)->"West",
                                    c(4,5)->"East")})
```

I just would like to recode the rows 1,2,3 into West and 4,5 into East. I know for sure that I ran that recode command a week ago and it worked perfectly. Now I get error.

```
 Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, nl, value = list(East = c(4, 5), West = c(1,  : 
        replacement element 2 has 3 rows, need 20
        In addition: Warning message:
        In if (as.factor.result) { :
        the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I just figured out the problem. I dont know whether that is common sense, but I didnt know it. The problem occurs only when I add library(car) to my script. I suppose some problems may arise using both  library(memisc) and library(car). Using both you will get the error message.

Comment: This week it works for me. If we don't know what error you get, it's going to be hard to help you.

Comment: I did run the code without any error.

Comment: This is crazy. Now I restarted Rstudio and reran the upper command. I dont get any error messages. however, e hasnt been recoded.

Comment: @HiThere.  I run the code on `Version 0.98.507` R studio and it went fine.  I admit that it is a bit old version.

Comment: I use Version 0.98.1017 on Mac 10.8.6. Now it works. But I have to restart Rstudio everytime otherwise I get the error message.

Answer (score 1):

How about amending it slightly to this?
Use the car library instead of memisc

```
require(car)
df_p1<- within(df,{
  e<-recode(e, "c(1,2,3)='West'; c(4,5)='East'")})
```

Comment: @HiThere Can you test the more simple code `recode(df$e, "c(1,2,3)='West'; c(4,5)='East'")` to see if it is even switching appropriately?  I also tested this with the _memisc_ package too.